# Powershell script does not exit

Tags: powershell, script

Powershell script does not exit

I am trying to run the output of Powershell script in the HTML format through Bladelogic

The script runs but does not exit

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Position=0,ValuefromPipeline=$true)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:ComputerName 

)
$cpuload = ((Get-Counter -Counter "\\$ComputerName\Process(*)\% Processor Time" -ea 0).CounterSamples) | Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending | Select-Object -First 20 |Select-Object InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100).toString('P')}}
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"
$cpuload | ConvertTo-Html -head $a -body "<H2>CPU LOAD</H2>" | Out-File -FilePath C:\tmp\dis.txt
#Invoke-Expression C:\tmp\dis1.txt
#cat C:\tmp\dis1.txt
Get-Content 'C:\tmp\dis.txt' | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '^<html.*$', ("<html>")} | Set-Content 'C:\tmp\dis1.txt'
cat C:\tmp\dis1.txt
```

Comment: Which OS and PowerShell version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Your script runs on my computer (PowerShell 5.1), however I notice the following in your script:

- [`[cmdletbinding()]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute) is a function attribute, it is not designed for
  scripts.
- I also see that your `$ComputerName` parameter is a string array with pipeline input allowed, if
  you plan to run this for multiple computer names you should consider
  using [`begin process end`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413265.aspx).

Comment: That's a good point, perhaps the OP meant to make it as a function instead and pass the parameter to it instead for the $env:ComputerName str data type? Is this how they'd go about getting the expected result?